# What Code Signing Certificate products provide both the public and private key for manually signing apps?

Tags: windows, ssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I recently acquired an (OV) Code Signing Certificate from SSL.com and subscribed to their eSigner service, which comes with a monthly fee. However, I've found this subscription model to be less than ideal for my needs, as I'd rather not commit to monthly payments for signing services.

Upon further investigation, I realized that the Code Signing Certificate from SSL.com only provides the public key. To sign my application, I need access to the private key, which is generated by eSigner called a "Code Signing Request"

Now, I'm actively seeking an (OV) Code Signing Certificate suitable for my Windows C# application that offers both the public and private keys. This would enable me to manually sign my application without being tied to a monthly subscription for the private key.

All support and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You create a CSR on your own device, upload it to SSL.com to sign, then merge it back in. SSL.com doesn't have the private key, you keep that on your device. See eg https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/creating-csr-iis-10 Or you can use eSigner, and ask them for the private key.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#, and should probably be migrated to [sf]

Comment: @Charlieface using eSigner means I have to pay monthly and it's not what I want, I want a product which enable me to manually sign my app without a subscription

Comment: So do it yourself using the Windows Certificates MMC snap-in as linked.